# Like a car key fob, but for a light on my hat

Tags: circuit-design

I need a way for someone who is stuck in bed to summon me when I'm outside using a line trimmer, lawn mower, or chain saw.  Those tools prevent me from hearing a cell phone or walkie talkie ringing or feel it vibrating.  Headphones on those devices allow too much incoming noise, so I have to stick to using earplugs.  What components would it take to assemble a remote controlled flasher like this (I haven't been able to find an existing product online):
[image]

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Daytech-Emergency-Waterproof-Business-Flashing/dp/B0936B7P74  Daytech Remote Emergency Strobe Siren Alarm Kit Waterproof Outdoor Loud Panic Sos Warning System for Business Home Shop Hotel School 800ft 1 Red Flashing Siren+ 2 Call Buttons

Comment: There are devices [like this](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B077VMC89R), which can reach quite a distance and provide you with an alert when someone just pushes a button. They are cheap. And they work and they are very loud.

Answer (score 1):

- better headphones plugged into the phone will work with an air-tight seal.
- or cheaper solution, use your existing safety ear protection and additional blocking using SkullCandy $20 earbuds plugged into the phone. These provide an additional 40 dB or more attenuation depending on the fit of optional size mushroom insert adapters. Don't use solid earbuds.

https://www.skullcandy.ca/shop/earbuds/wired-earbuds/

Now let's call it the earFOB. ;)  Can U see the light?